# How to protect against pushing large binary blobs in git?

Tags: git, binaryfiles, githooks

I have a central git repository which myself and several collaborators regularly push and pull from. In the past I have committed a large binary blob by accident, which requires rebasing to fully delete and is a pain for everyone, so I'd like to protect against this happening in the future. Is it possible to setup a hook in the remote repository that will check the file size of files being pushed (whether they are being added new or an existing file is updated) and reject pushes with files above a threshold size, say 2MB?

Importantly I want existing files already greater than 2MB that are untouched to be tolerated (so a push shouldn't be rejected if a 2MB file is already in the repository, only if the push adds a 2MB file or grows an existing file to be 2MB). Also, I want the hook to execute on the remote side so I don't have to worry that clients don't have to have a hook setup.

Edit: Since a push can contain multiple commits, and even one commit with a large file gets it stuck in the repo, I want to protect against pushes that contain /any commit/ that grows to or adds a >=2MB file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like the [pre-receive hook](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html) would be the correct place for this check. This hook executes on the server side of a push, and has access to enough information for you to implement a file size check.

> This hook is invoked by *git-receive-pack* on the remote repository, which happens when a *git push* is done on a local repository. Just before starting to update refs on the remote repository, the pre-receive hook is invoked. Its exit status determines the success or failure of the update.

Comment: The pre-receive hook happens before "updating refs", does that mean it's done early enough that if I have a nonzero exit the size of the repo doesn't grow, or just that it doesn't apply the commit, leaving the blob still there to be cloned? I think I read the latter but I can't find the link anymore :/

Comment: If you fail the pre-commit hook, the blob will still be present on the server but that doesn't automatically mean it will be cloned. It won't be reachable from any of the server's refs, so Git will pretty much ignore it. Eventually Git's garbage collection will remove the unreferenced blob.

Comment: Do you know how to determine the size of the push? That would make this answer more complete. I have a pre-receive script reading the lines off stdin, and I can find the files associated with the objects in objects/$FIRST_OBJECT_CHAR$SECOND_OBJECT_CHAR/$REST_OF_CHARS but I'm not sure if I can just use the newer object's file size or what.

Comment: It appears you can use "git cat-file -p" on the oldref and newref sha hashes to get their tree hashes, then do the same on the tree hashes to get the blob hashes, and then do a "git cat-file -s" on the blob hashes to get their sizes. I'm still figuring out how this works with multiple commits and files though...